# Is it possible to watch videos on YouTube in 1080p or higher resolution for midori browser?

Tags: midori

The highest resolution which can be chosen on YouTube for midori browser is 720p, is there any way to watch them in 1080p or higher resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem come here: https://www.youtube.com/html5

Midori is light but with less features then the services example youtube can't use extra feature (1080p videos example).

I choose (*I'm sad about it because I like midori browser*) Chrome for leave this problems back to me :)

Comment: Firefox can also play 4K or 1080p 60fps YouTube videos without problems by default now